# encrypt words cycle shift value to each letter from the end of its word java script

Tags: javascript

I want to encrypt words cycle shift  value to each letter from the end of its word java script.
The value of this cycle shift is determined by the postion of the letter from the end of it's word. The shift value for each letter of word is its index value (starting from 0) right most character of the word.

```
function encryptWords(str) {
    // you can comment this line
    str = str.toLowerCase();

    var result = '';
    var charcode = 0;

    for (var i = str.length -1 ; i > = 0; i--) {
        charcode = (str[i].charCodeAt()) + i;
        result += String.fromCharCode(charcode);
    }
    return result;

}
console.log(encryptWords('yum feed'));
```

for example, the shift values in `"yum feed"` are

```
yum : m-> 0, u -> 1, y -> 2;
feed : d->0, e->1, e->2, f->3
"avm igfd"
```

Comment: what is use of `num`?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you handle the shift on a Caesar cipher in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36814804/how-do-you-handle-the-shift-on-a-caesar-cipher-in-javascript)

Comment: updated my question

Comment: Can you please explain what is the expected behavior and what's the actual behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine for a single word.

But for a string containing *2 or more words*, you can try using [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) twice: once for *words* and once for *chars in those words*.

```js
function CaesarCipher(str, num) {
  // you can comment this line
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  var charcode = 0;

  var result = str.split(' ').map(
    val => val.split('').map(
      (c, i) => {
        // shifting of the chars, based on their index values
        charcode = 97 + (
          (c.charCodeAt() + val.length - 1 - i) - 97
      //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ shift
        ) % 26; 
      //  ^^^^ to avoid chars higher than 'z'
      
        return String.fromCharCode(charcode);
      }
    ).join('')
  ).join(' ');
  
  return result;
}
console.log(CaesarCipher('yum feed', 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function encryptWords(str) {
    return str
        .split(' ')
        .map(s => [...s]
            .map((c, i) => String.fromCharCode(97 + (c.charCodeAt(0) + s.length - i - 98) % 26))
            .join('')
        )
        .join(' ');
}

console.log(encryptWords('yum feed'));
```